# AS3 How would I make a figure do different animations based on keyboard input?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am using Action script 3, and CS5.5. I wish to make my character animate different ways based on keyboard input. Like say if I press the right arrow key I want my run animation to start, and if I press the left arrow key I want to reverse that same animation. Then When there is no input I want him to be just standing, and when the up arrow key is pushed I want the jump animation to work. What is the best way to do this in action script 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use frame labels to programmatically control the movement of the playhead on the timeline.

MEDIA

The character clip should have this structure:

-3 layers on the timeline, each with three keyframes for nine in all

--a frame label layer, giving a frame label to each frame ("standing", "walkingRight", "walkingLeft")

--a stops layer, which make each frame separate, so movement between the frames is only controlled by code

--a sub-animations layer, with one animation in each frame, all the animation looping and having no stops in them

---walk left animation clip

---walk right animation clip

---standing animation clip

Just to be clear, each of these nested animations takes up one frame, but if you move the playhead over it, it looks like that animation is playing alone, and it stays that way until your code moves the playhead.

CODE IT

```
var character:MovieClip=new MyCharacterClass()
addChild(character);
character.gotoAndStop("standing") 
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUp); 

protected function keyUp(event:KeyEvent):void
{
   switch (event.keyCode)
{
    case Keyboard.LEFT:
        character.gotoAndStop("walkingLeft")
    break;

    case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        character.gotoAndStop("walkingRight")
    break;

    default:
        character.gotoAndStop("standing")
    break;
}
}
```

This is the simplest possible example--click the left arrow, and the animation shows the character walking left (albeit in one spot, you need to add that actual movement code). Click the right arrow and it walks right. Press any other key and the character stands.

Comment: hmmm... Slightly confusing instructions. could you explain a little more in depth, and for a total beginner =D. I think I kinda understand what you are saying, but I am not used to using the timeline to input code. Could I do this with event listeners in my games constructor?

Comment: Example updated. For traditional programmers, the timeline is quite weird. You don't need to code any more than a "stop();" in the timeline, but you do have to structure your media so it can be manipulated like you want.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that

Answer (score 0):

First off, you use KeyboardEvent to check for arrow keys being pressed. Then what exactly you do in the event listener function depends on how exactly your animations were created. For example, if what you're doing is playing MovieClips that were drawn in Flash, then switch the MovieClip in the KeyboardEvent listener.

Comment: Alright but all of my animations are in one movieclip if that makes sense. I have one of him standing. Then another of him running, and one him jumping. How do I access different parts of the animation? Also how do I reverse the animation? Like if they press the left key I wish for it to be facing left, and right if right key is pressed.

Comment: Can you change the movieclip? If so, splitting different animations into differenct movieclips is simpler than doing code gymnastics to deal with a non-ideal setup.

Comment: If I do that though wouldn't it make it more complicated when I do collision detection?

Comment: Also that fact that I would need a new class for each one.

Comment: It seems to me that there should be a way to do this.